# Renaming files from a folder, by changing the prefixes in the front of the filename, depening in the number of files in the folder

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have downloaded some files an named them using numbers as prefixes to have them in order(are videos):

```
_01_filename
_02_filename
_10_filename
_100_filename
_101_filename
....
_20_filename
```

As you can see in the example above 100 is immediately after *10* not after *99*

So, I want to read them and rename them as *001*, *020* in this case.

Actually check the number of files, and depending on their number, determine the number of zeros(in front)

So, I'm thinking of creating a list with folders to scan:

```
[folder1, folder2, folder3,...]
```

and get the total number of the files.

No, I have to maintain their previous order, not to screw the order. Sorting by name is not an option because I will get *100* after 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import os
import re

filenames = os.listdir()


def rename(old_filename,new_filename):
    old_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), old_filename)
    new_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), new_filename)
    try:
        os.rename(old_path, new_path)
        return True
    except:
        return False

for file in filenames:
    #removing underscores if any in starting of name
    if file[0] == '_':
        length = len(file)
        newfilename = file[1:length]
        #finding integers in string (finidng in starting four letters only)
        digit = re.findall('\d+',newfilename[0:3])
        #formatting numbers with prefix zero
        y = digit[0]
        newdigit = '{:03}'.format(int(y))

        newfiletemp = newfilename.lstrip(y)

        newfile = newdigit + newfiletemp

        rename(file,newfile)
```

[Before Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ob45E.png)

[After Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ocrrc.png)

Comment: if your file names are as you mentioned then this code must work in the same directory

Comment: @user3541631 if the file name has more than 3 numeric prefix...it will rename it to three digits....you can change this by editing newfilename[0:3]  to newfilename[0:5] or the limit according to your file names

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the maximum width of the numeric prefixes in the file list first, and then use `str.rjust` to pad `'0'`s to the prefixes to that width.

The following example assumes you have your list of file names stored in the list `l`:

```
from os import rename
l = ['_01_filename',
'_02_filename',
'_10_filename',
'_100_filename',
'_101_filename']
w = max(map(lambda s: len(s.split('_')[1]), l))
for f in l:
    p, i, n = f.split('_', 2)
    rename(f, '_'.join(((p, i.rjust(w, '0'), n))))
```

Comment: I'm thinking of scanning the folders; see updated question